# How to tackle byte stuffing in Java?

Tags: java, io, binaryfiles

I'm reading a binary file in Java that is byte-stuffed when saved, therefore the operation must be reversed when reading. The stuffing lies in adding an extra zero byte after an `FF` byte. That zero byte must be discarded when reading. I'm using a `DataInputStream` to read the file, though that shouldn't make much of a difference, seeing how I'm only using the "raw" read-to-array function for that portion of the program.

Anyway, here's what I've got so far :

```
public static byte[] unstuff(byte[] stuffed) {
    int bytesToSkip = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<stuffed.length - 1;++i) {
        if(stuffed[i] == 0xFF && stuffed[i+1] == 0) {
            ++bytesToSkip;
        }
    }
    if(bytesToSkip == 0) return stuffed;

    byte unstuffed[] = new byte[stuffed.length - bytesToSkip];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<stuffed.length - 1;++i) {
        if(stuffed[i] == 0xFF && stuffed[i+1] == 0) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            unstuffed[j] = stuffed[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return unstuffed;
}
```

Basically, the function counts the number of bytes to be skipped, then allocates an array that's shorter than the original stuffed array by that number of bytes, and copies them over, skipping the unwanted zero bytes.

The question is : is there any other way to do this, perhaps more slick, more efficient, more straightforward? Would putting the bytes in another container and then removing them instead of copying over the whole array work better?

Comment: Write to a byteArrayOutputStream as you're scanning the array and after scanning the input array, use the `toByteArray()` method to convert the ByteArayOutputStream to a byte array. Incidenta;;y why `for(int i=0;i<stuffed.length - 1;++i) {` you;re skipping the last character here. Consider an array of 3 elements. It's length is 3 and it's indices are 0, 1 and 2 therefore you want to continue while `i < array.length`, not `i< length-1` as that would only give you 2 iterations for i = 0 and i=1.

Comment: @SteveAtkinson The answer to you question lies in `stuffed[i+1]`.

Comment: that assumes the array always ends with the FF 00 sequence, which wasn't stated ;)

Comment: @SteveAtkinson No, it doesn't assume anything beyond the obvious truth that an array whose next-to-last byte is not `ff` does not end in `ff 00`.

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal way would be to use the original array for the `FF 00` squashing. Whenever the condition is met, don't increment the target index. When you are done, the array will contain the sequence you want, but it will be possibly too large, with extra bytes at the end. Then you either copy to a shorter array, or use the original as-is, but pass it into methods that accept offset + count into the array, passing the lower bytecount.

```
int target = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < stuffed.length; ++i) {
    if (stuffed[i-1] == 0xFF && stuffed[i] == 0) continue;
    if (i != target) stuffed[target++] = stuffed[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a wrapper around the `InputStream` itself:

```
new DataInputStream(new FilterInputStream(stream)) {
  int buf = -1;

  public int read() {
    if (buf != -1) {
      int result = buf;
      buf = -1;
      return result;
    } else {
      int b = super.read();
      if (b == 0xFF) {
        super.skip(1); // skip the 0 byte
      }
      return b;
    }
  }

  public int read(byte[] bytes, int off, int len) {
    int dst = 0;
    while (dst == 0) {
      int readBytes = super.read(bytes, off, len);
      if (readBytes == -1) return -1;
      int dst = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++) {
        bytes[off + dst] = bytes[off + i];
        if (bytes[off + i] == (byte) 0xFF) {
          i++; // skip the 0 byte afterwards
        }
      }
    }
    return dst;
  }
}
```